# Oracle Data Modeler - Diagram notation

Tags: oracle, database-design, datamodel, data-modeling

Is there a **detailed notational guide** for the Relational model diagrams generated by the *Oracle Data Modeler*?

---

I'm using Oracle Data Modeler to **generate Relational Models for an existing database**. It generated a diagram, but I'm not able to decode all the notations in the diagram.

> Some of the **notations** are:
>
> 1. arrows
> 2. asterisks (red)
> 3. Aphabetical notations (like P, F)
> 4. Symbols (like diamond, key)
> 5. Abbreviations (like IX)
>
> By mere inference, the above **correspond to**:
>
> 1. foreign key references
> 2. ??
> 3. P - Private key; F - Foreign key
> 4. key - Private key
> 5. ??

However, I'm wondering if there is a detailed notational guide for the *Oracle Data Modeler*?

I searched for it online, but could find none.

Comment: Also letter U exists there, it means Unique.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

- **P symbol** before a Column name: the column is the "**Primary key**" ("P" for Primary) of the EntityType; Note that you can have two or more columns with a P symbol as a Primary key can be made of several columns
- **F symbol** before a Column name: the column is a "**Foreign key**" ("F" for Foreign) which mean this column is referencing the Primary Key of another entity; Not that you can have several Foreign keys
- **PF symbol** together: the column is both a **Primary key and a Foreign key**
- **"*"** symbol (**red asterisk**): the **column** has a **NOT NULL constraint**; in other words, you can't insert a row (also called an "instance" of the Entity Type) in this table without a value for this column)
- **Diamond shape symbol** (at the bottom of a Table): show the **INDEXES** on that table (in general the Primary Key is automatically an Index

Comment: the `*` we saw it on day to day basis when filling forms on the web. Funny enough, I just wonder if this is where the actual source of it.

Answer (score 2):

Red asterisks usually are mandatory, Diamonds in most ERDs indicate a relation to. pk and fk are private and foreign keys if I recall correctly. I'm not sure what you mean by arrows, do you mean crows feet notation?

Answer (score 1):

I think data modeler has a section in the settings to show which ER notation it is using. One can change or see the notation there. 
for my mac;

```
Preferences -> Data Modeler -> Diagram -> Logical Model
```

there you can see the used notation. And so that you can check online for more information of the arrows etc..